# Watertight connector for NEMA 3R trough underneath NEMA 3R panel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, code-compliance

What is the correct product for connecting a NEMA 3R wiring trough underneath a NEMA 3R meter main?

Is it just 2 Myers-type hubs with a close nipple, or is there a simpler, ready-made way?

Comment: What make and model is your wiring trough, or can you at least tell us if it has a hub footprint somewhere on its top vs. having a solid top with no marks, punches, or KOs?

Comment: ^ ThreePhaseEel is possibly our strongest expert in this area... worth answering those questions.

Comment: It has a solid top with no punches, marks, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use a single Myers hub in the top of the trough

Since you don't have punches for a bolted (NEMA 3R) hub available to you on the trough top, you'll have to use a Myers (NEMA 4/4X) hub instead.  However, you don't need such a hub fitting coming out of the bottom of a NEMA 3R panel, so you can simply use locknuts on the nipple coming out of the Myers hub to make that connection.